# Passing the output of a glue job as input of the next glue job in AWS Step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

I have a step function which looks something takes input and passes it to a glue job . The glue job does some operation and the output of the first is passed as input of the next step function glue job.

Here is my step function code:

```
{
  "StartAt": "Job1",
  "States": {
    "Job1": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "Job1",
        "Arguments": {
          "input.$": "$.input"
        }
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.job1Result",
      "Next": "Job2"
    },
    "Job2": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "Job2",
        "Arguments": {
          "input.$": "$.job1Result.output_value"
        }
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.job2Result",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

My glue script looks like this:

Job1 Script :

```
import sys
import json
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

# Initialize the GlueContext
sparkContext = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sparkContext)

# Get the input from the output of Job1
input_value = sys.argv[1]

# Append "ed" to the input
output_value = input_value + "pass"

# Structure the result as a dictionary
result = {
    "output_value": output_value
}

# Convert the result to a JSON string
result_json = json.dumps(result)

# Print the JSON result to the console
print(result_json)
```

Job2 script :

```
import sys
import json
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

# Initialize the GlueContext
sparkContext = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sparkContext)

# Get the input from the output of Job1
input_value = sys.argv[1]

# Append "ed" to the input
output_value = input_value + "ed"

# Structure the result as a dictionary
result = {
    "output_value": output_value
}

# Convert the result to a JSON string
result_json = json.dumps(result)

# Print the JSON result to the console
print(result_json)
```

I am not able to understand how to send the output of my first glue job to the step function that is input to glue job in next step function.

[Step functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeJyh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Glue jobs don't have a built-in way to send data directly to an application or service without saving it first in places like Amazon S3 or databases. It's a good idea to use external storage for keeping your in-between data, especially when you're managing multiple Glue jobs in a single ETL workflow.

Comment: Yes after some research i got that.